# How to use filter in GeoExt.FeatureStore?

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, geoext

I have a FeatureStore:

```
        var protocol=new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
            url: "/geoserver/ows?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&typeName=xxxx:lineview&srsName=EPSG:4326&outputFormat=GML2",
    });
    zoomStore_disp = new GeoExt.data.FeatureStore({
        layer: myVecLayer_disp,
        fields: [
            {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
            {name: 'name_dispatcher', type: 'String'},
            {name: 'voltage', type: 'String'},
        ],
        proxy: new GeoExt.data.ProtocolProxy({
            protocol: protocol,
        }),
        autoLoad: true,
    });
```

But lineview layer contains too much features. So I must wait a lot of time before store is load. Is it possible to load in store features by filter?

I can't find any examples or documentations how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah it was stupid question. But if someone interest for filter features you can use Openlayers.filter something like this:

```
        var protocol=new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
            url: "/geoserver/ows?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&typeName=xxxx:lineview&srsName=EPSG:4326&outputFormat=GML2",
    });
    featureFilter = new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
        type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.LIKE,
        property: "name_dispatcher",
        value:'value'
    });
    searchStore = new GeoExt.data.FeatureStore({
        layer: myVecLayer_disp,
        fields: [
            {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
            {name: 'name_dispatcher', type: 'String'},
            {name: 'voltage', type: 'String'},
        ],
        proxy: new GeoExt.data.ProtocolProxy({
            protocol: protocol,
        }),
        featureFilter:featureFilter,
        autoLoad: true,
    });
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation now please mark this as resolved.